# Pipe of two commands with fork,execvp and then rederict the output to socket

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, fork, exec

I have two commands cmd1 and cmd2 and I have to execute cmd1 in a child, redirect the output to another child and then execute cmd2 with the output of cmd1 as an argument. Then I have to redirect the output to a remote client (telnet) connected with a socket. I can't figure out the problem but my solution doesn't redirect cmd1 output to cmd2.

```
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        //Process to compute cmd1
        char *arg[2];
        arg[0] = cmd1;
        arg[1] = NULL;
        dup(piped[1]);
        close(piped[0]);
        close(piped[1]);
        execvp(cmd1,arg);

    }
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        //Process to compute cmd2
        dup2(newsockfd,STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(newsockfd,STDERR_FILENO);
        char *arg[2];
        arg[0] = cmd2;
        arg[1] = NULL;
        dup(piped[0]);
        close(piped[0]);
        close(piped[1]);
        execvp(cmd2,arg);
    }
```

Just to be clear. The problem is not in socket inizilization or pipe that's why I reported only the main part

Comment: Why would you expect anything to be redirected from cmd1? You're not doing anything with the input or output to that child process.

Comment: That's the problem. How can debug the code for example a printf that shows the output of    execvp(cmd1,arg); in the second child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, what you want would be like something below

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    //Process to compute cmd1
    char *arg[2];
    arg[0] = cmd1;
    arg[1] = NULL;
    dup2(piped[1],STDOUT_FILENO); //Redirect stdout to pipe's write end
    dup2(piped[1],STDERR_FILENO); //Redirect stderr to pipe's write end
    close(piped[0]);
    close(piped[1]);
    close(newsockfd);
    execvp(cmd1,arg);
}

if(fork() == 0)
{
    //Process to compute cmd2
    char *arg[2];
    arg[0] = cmd2;
    arg[1] = NULL;
    dup2(piped[0],STDIN_FILENO); //Redirect pipe's read end to stdin
    dup2(newsockfd,STDOUT_FILENO); //Redirect stdout to socket
    dup2(newsockfd,STDERR_FILENO); //Redirect stderr to socket
    close(piped[0]);
    close(piped[1]);
    close(newsockfd);
    execvp(cmd2,arg);
}

close(piped[0]);
close(piped[1]);
close(newsockfd);
```

Comment: I think it's correct. I tried it but it doesn't show anything in the telnet console client. The execvp(cmd2,arg); should have the output of execvp(cmd1,arg); as argument but how is possible with that code?

Comment: As of the telnet part, I can't reach any further conclusions with your current code. Perhaps you can simply write(newsockfd, "abc", 3) to see if it appears on the other end. As for the argument part, maybe I didn't understand you correctly. Do you want cmd1's output(stdout & stderr) to be cmd2's stdin or cmd2's command line argument? The above code will achieve the former not the latter.

Comment: The telnet client works. I want cmd1's output to be the cmd2's command line argument. I'm trying to implement the normal pipe command in linux cmd1|cmd2. So the first child executes cmd1 then the second child executes cmd2 with the output of cmd1 as command line argument. For example ls|sort. The first child executes Cmd1 then the output string goes to the second child that executes sort with the string from the first child

Comment: You contradict yourself. The pipe | in the command line would redirect the stdout of the cmd on the left to the stdin of the command on the right, just as my code will do(with the difference of the stderr). Maybe you can changes the cmd2 to cat and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, i'm doing my best to be clear as much as possible. How does the execvp(cmd2,arg); understand that its argument is the output of execvp(cmd1,arg); in your code? That is what I can't understand.

Comment: It doesn't. All cmd2 knows is that it is running and there are things that can be read from stdin. I think I need to be clear here. You do want to duplicate the effect of a '|', as NOT having the output of cmd1 as a string and use it as the first COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT of cmd2 (i.e. mkdir abc) right?

Comment: I want for example cmd1 = ls  and cmd2= sort. ls will pass the list of file to sort and the sort will show the list sorted. That's all, like a "|"

Comment: Then the code above should work (ignoring the stderr part for now). So have you tried to set cmd2 as 'cat' and test it? Cause 'cat' will simply read from stdin and write directly to stdout so you can get the output from cmd1 in the telnet and see if the entire thing works or not.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KuAgNrx7 If you want to have a look at the entire code

Comment: I've tested your full program, the basic idea is right. After testing, I discovered that I have made a mistake: using 'cat' as cmd2 won't work as it will fail. There are two things that your program need to change: 1. if execvp fails, the child should print some error then exit; 2. your way of getting cmd1 and cmd2 can only handle command without command line arguments thus not very useful. I've tested using cmd2 as 'cat -' (with one command line argument) and the program works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know but I don't need to manage command line arguments. Have you tried with ls|sort? Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Finally, I've made it. https://pastebin.com/qSMDJJjp One small thing: cmd2 has a '\n' in the end so it will not execute

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH